# Not able to select multiple checkboxes in selenium(java)

Tags: java, selenium

I want to select multiple checkboxes in selenium and below is the code I tried. With this, only the 1st option gets selected and not all. Kindly advise.

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");      
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Maxi Dresses");      
driver.findElement(By.className("vh79eN")).click();         
String parentWindow= driver.getWindowHandle();      
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);                
Set<String> strHandles= driver.getWindowHandles();                          
   for(String childWindow : strHandles){                                                    
       driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);                       
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);                      
       List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//section//div[contains(text(),'Brand')]/../following-sibling ::div//div[1]//div//div//div//input/following sibling :: div[1]"));
       int listSize= elements.size();       
       for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++){                               
           elements.get(i).click(); 
       }                                    
   }
```

Comment: format the code properly.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.